# Is that possible to import from different modules in google colaboratory?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am using google colaboratory. I have a 'utils.ipynb' which contains some useful functions. For example:

> load_image(path)

I have another 'models.ipynb' in which I want to use the codes in 'utils.ipynb'. How should I do that? For example, how can I import load_image from 'utils.ipynb'?

This code does not work by the way:

> from utils import load_image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import from a .py file, not from a .ipynb file.

So,

- copy the code in .ipynb into a text file and name it utils.py
- upload utils.py to Google Colab
- `from utils import load_images`

Comment: I did, but it did not work. I get 'no module named utils'.

Comment: You need to upload utils.py first, using google.colab.files.upload()

Comment: Thank you. It works now, however, it seems a little hard this way. Consider if you had many modules and stuff. I wish there was an easier way to do that so you could have all your project there.

Comment: You can upload many files at a time. If you have really many many files, you can zip them, upload, then unzip them all.

Comment: Yeah, uploading one or many files is not the problem. The problem is that you like to have all modules of your project in google colab and be able to edit them easily with colab notebook as well.